How to get mouse position then copy the position into clipboard. In AutoHotKey V2
I want to click a keybind "f4" then I want to get the mouse position, then store it on my clipboard
f4::
{
    MouseGetPos (&MouseX, &MouseY)
    pos:= &MouseX , &MouseY
    ;I want to add tooltip showing the pos, but don't know how to 
    A_Clipboard := ""
    A_Clipboard := pos 
    Send "^c"
    ClipWait 2, 1
    MsgBox "Copied position"
}

I feel like the answer is very simple, but I've searched around and found nothing.

@TylerH I want to click a keybind "f4" then I want to get the mouse position, then store it on my clipboard.

When you are dealing with strings it may be confusing at start but you need to use %var% to access inside because ahk compiler/interpreter won't know if you want text "var" or the value inside var. Also creating a tooltip official_documentation
F4::
MouseGetPos,MouseX,MouseY
pos = (%MouseX%,%MouseY%) ;Formatted as (x,y)
ToolTip,%pos%,%MouseX%,%MouseY% ;Create a tooltip at x,y with pos text
A_Clipboard = %pos%
MsgBox,,,"Copied position"
return


The question specifically asks about AHKv2. Your answer is not only AHKv1, but ancient AHKv1 which uses legacy syntax.

Here's a v2 answer as requested:
#Requires AutoHotkey v2

;Otherwise MouseGetPos is relative to active window
CoordMode("Mouse", "Screen") 


F4::
{
    MouseGetPos(&PosX, &PosY)
    pos := "(" PosX ", " PosY ")"
    A_Clipboard := pos
    ToolTip(pos)
}


Try the following code:-
f4::
{
    MouseGetPos(&MouseX, &MouseY)
    pos := "(" MouseX "," MouseY ")"
    Tooltip "Mouse pos is " pos ;Add tooltips like that
    Sleep 500
    Tooltip "" ;Clear tooltip after 5s
    A_Clipboard := pos
    MsgBox "Copied position"
}

It is very straightforward. Please feel free to remove the comments if you like. 
Changes:-

Removed unnecessary A_Clipboard := "" line

Added ToolTip showing the variable pos

Removed redundant lines


Hope this is what you need! (This is for v2)

Edit:- See CoordMode if you want positions relative to the display (use CoordMode "Mouse" in this case). The AHK server seems to be currently down, so I unfortunately cannot link to the CoordMode section on the website. For now, take this from the offline documentation:-


❝CoordMode Sets coordinate mode for various built-in functions to be relative to either the active window or the screen.❞


Edit 2:- Got it! Here, click this link.

